# Launching An External Shortcut

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch an external shortcut, What i have is only the activity path .

Here's what i did :

```
        try {
            view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.getIntentOld(List.getShortcutPath());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Log :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=com.sonyericsson.music.ArtistShortcutActivity }
```

The Path I'm trying to launch :

```
com.sonyericsson.music.ArtistShortcutActivity
```

How to launch the shortcut ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

if you get permission denial error, then add `android:exported` XML attribute is `true` in the manifest for the activity you want to launch

Here `com.example` is the package name of the app your activity that you want to launch is in, and com.example.myexampleactivity the full name of the activity you want to launch

If the intended activity to launch is package private, then you wont be able to launch it from a foreign application activity. This is done for security reasons by Google